# How can I support Arabic Language in Android PDF document?

Tags: android

I have a problem in writing to a PDF document in android when I trying to write in Arabic Language!

My function like this:

```
public void createPDF() {
    Document doc = new Document();
     try {
            FileOutputStream fOut = null;

            String Fnampdf="testfile"  + ".pdf";
            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File directory = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/newfolder1");
            directory.mkdirs();
            File file = new File(directory, Fnampdf);

            fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, fOut);

            //open the document
            doc.open();

            Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("Hi! I am generating my first PDF using DroidText");
            Font paraFont= new Font(Font.COURIER);
            p1.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
            p1.setFont(paraFont);

             //add paragraph to document    
             doc.add(p1);

             Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph("This is an example of a simple paragraph");
             Font paraFont2= new Font(Font.COURIER,14.0f,Color.GREEN);
             p2.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
             p2.setFont(paraFont2);

             doc.add(p2);

             //set footer
             Phrase footerText = new Phrase("This is an example of a footer");
             HeaderFooter pdfFooter = new HeaderFooter(footerText, false);
             doc.setFooter(pdfFooter);


     } catch (DocumentException de) {
             Log.e("PDFCreator", "DocumentException:" + de);
     } catch (IOException e) {
             Log.e("PDFCreator", "ioException:" + e);
     } 
     finally {
             doc.close();
     }

}
```

But when I attempt to write in Arabic Language it does not work with me, as:

```
Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("برنامج كشف حساب .. ");
```

How can I support Arabic Language in Pdf?

Any help will be appreciated !
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem can be solved by using the jar file called DynamicPDF.jar where you can download it from this link: https://www.assembla.com/code/zapisyUG/subversion/nodes/zapisWAR/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/DynamicPDF.jar?_format=raw&rev=133

Once you have downloaded and added the library, you need to use an additional class "Farsi.java" which contains a utility function that has the ability to encode Arabic sentence in the right way.

However, it is important to use a font (.ttf) file in order to identify and map the Arabic character in the right way. Thus, you need to download the desired font file called "tahoma.ttf" which can bed found and downloaded from this link :
http://www.fontsupply.com/fonts/T/Tahoma.html

To sum up, you need to do the following :
1- Download the DynamicPDF.jar and then add it to your project.
2- Create a new java file named "Farsi.java" and then copy the code which can be found below. 
3- Download the "tahoma.ttf" font file and then add it on "/storage/sdcard0" (your smart phone).
4- Finally, copy the following code to be run in your onCreate function.

I hope everything goes well.

```
public class DynamicPDFHelloWorld extends Activity {
    private static String FILE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/HelloWorld.pdf";
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // Create a document and set it'ss properties
    Document objDocument = new Document();
    objDocument.setCreator("DynamicPDFHelloWorld.java");
    objDocument.setAuthor("Your Name");
    objDocument.setTitle("Hello World");


    String convertedText="";

    TrueTypeFont trueTypeFont = new TrueTypeFont(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/tahoma.ttf" );

    // Create a page to add to the document
    Page objPage = new Page(PageSize.LETTER, PageOrientation.PORTRAIT,
            54.0f);

    convertedText=Farsi.Convert("برنامج كشف حساب .. ");
    // Create a Label to add to the page

    Label objLabel = new Label(convertedText, 0, 0, 504, 100,
            trueTypeFont, 18, TextAlign.RIGHT);
    objLabel.setRightToLeft(true);

    // Add label to page
    objPage.getElements().add(objLabel);

    // Add page to document
    objDocument.getPages().add(objPage);

    try {
        // Outputs the document to file
        objDocument.draw(FILE);

        Toast.makeText(this, "File has been written to :" + FILE,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Error, unable to write to file\n" + e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;

public final class Farsi {

    public static boolean isFarsiConversionNeeded = true;

    private final static String szLamAndAlef = Character
            .toString((char) 0xfedf)
            + Character.toString((char) 0xfe8e); // Lam + Alef

private final static String szLamStickAndAlef = Character
        .toString((char) 0xfee0)
        + Character.toString((char) 0xfe8e); // Lam (Sticky !!!)+
                                                // Alef

private final static String szLa = Character.toString((char) 0xfefb); // La
private final static String szLaStick = Character.toString((char) 0xfefc); // La
                                                                            // (Sticky!!!)

private final static String szLamAndAlefWoosim = Character
        .toString((char) 0xe1)
        + Character.toString((char) 0xbb); // Lam + Alef

private final static String szLamStickAndAlefWoosim = Character
        .toString((char) 0x90)
        + Character.toString((char) 0xbb); // Lam (Sticky !!!)+
                                            // Alef

private final static String szLaWoosim = Character.toString((char) 0xd9); // La
private final static String szLaStickWoosim = Character
        .toString((char) 0xd9); // La

// (Sticky!!!)

private static final class struc {
    public char character;
    public char endGlyph;
    public char iniGlyph;
    public char midGlyph;
    public char isoGlyph;

    public struc(char Character, char EndGlyph, char IniGlyph,
            char MidGlyph, char IsoGlyph) {
        character = Character;
        endGlyph = EndGlyph;
        iniGlyph = IniGlyph;
        midGlyph = MidGlyph;
        isoGlyph = IsoGlyph;
    }
}

static struc[] arrStruc = {
        new struc((char) 0x630, (char) 0xfeac, (char) 0xfeab,
                (char) 0xfeac, (char) 0xfeab),
        new struc((char) 0x62f, (char) 0xfeaa, (char) 0xfea9,
                (char) 0xfeaa, (char) 0xfea9),
        new struc((char) 0x62c, (char) 0xfe9e, (char) 0xfe9f,
                (char) 0xfea0, (char) 0xfe9d),
        new struc((char) 0x62d, (char) 0xfea2, (char) 0xfea3,
                (char) 0xfea4, (char) 0xfea1),
        new struc((char) 0x62e, (char) 0xfea6, (char) 0xfea7,
                (char) 0xfea8, (char) 0xfea5),
        new struc((char) 0x647, (char) 0xfeea, (char) 0xfeeb,
                (char) 0xfeec, (char) 0xfee9),
        new struc((char) 0x639, (char) 0xfeca, (char) 0xfecb,
                (char) 0xfecc, (char) 0xfec9),
        new struc((char) 0x63a, (char) 0xfece, (char) 0xfecf,
                (char) 0xfed0, (char) 0xfecd),
        new struc((char) 0x641, (char) 0xfed2, (char) 0xfed3,
                (char) 0xfed4, (char) 0xfed1),
        new struc((char) 0x642, (char) 0xfed6, (char) 0xfed7,
                (char) 0xfed8, (char) 0xfed5),
        new struc((char) 0x62b, (char) 0xfe9a, (char) 0xfe9b,
                (char) 0xfe9c, (char) 0xfe99),
        new struc((char) 0x635, (char) 0xfeba, (char) 0xfebb,
                (char) 0xfebc, (char) 0xfeb9),
        new struc((char) 0x636, (char) 0xfebe, (char) 0xfebf,
                (char) 0xfec0, (char) 0xfebd),
        new struc((char) 0x637, (char) 0xfec2, (char) 0xfec3,
                (char) 0xfec4, (char) 0xfec1),
        new struc((char) 0x643, (char) 0xfeda, (char) 0xfedb,
                (char) 0xfedc, (char) 0xfed9),
        new struc((char) 0x645, (char) 0xfee2, (char) 0xfee3,
                (char) 0xfee4, (char) 0xfee1),
        new struc((char) 0x646, (char) 0xfee6, (char) 0xfee7,
                (char) 0xfee8, (char) 0xfee5),
        new struc((char) 0x62a, (char) 0xfe96, (char) 0xfe97,
                (char) 0xfe98, (char) 0xfe95),
        new struc((char) 0x627, (char) 0xfe8e, (char) 0xfe8d,
                (char) 0xfe8e, (char) 0xfe8d),
        new struc((char) 0x644, (char) 0xfede, (char) 0xfedf,
                (char) 0xfee0, (char) 0xfedd),
        new struc((char) 0x628, (char) 0xfe90, (char) 0xfe91,
                (char) 0xfe92, (char) 0xfe8f),
        new struc((char) 0x64a, (char) 0xfef2, (char) 0xfef3,
                (char) 0xfef4, (char) 0xfef1),
        new struc((char) 0x633, (char) 0xfeb2, (char) 0xfeb3,
                (char) 0xfeb4, (char) 0xfeb1),
        new struc((char) 0x634, (char) 0xfeb6, (char) 0xfeb7,
                (char) 0xfeb8, (char) 0xfeb5),
        new struc((char) 0x638, (char) 0xfec6, (char) 0xfec7,
                (char) 0xfec8, (char) 0xfec5),
        new struc((char) 0x632, (char) 0xfeb0, (char) 0xfeaf,
                (char) 0xfeb0, (char) 0xfeaf),
        new struc((char) 0x648, (char) 0xfeee, (char) 0xfeed,
                (char) 0xfeee, (char) 0xfeed),
        new struc((char) 0x629, (char) 0xfe94, (char) 0xfe93,
                (char) 0xfe93, (char) 0xfe93),
        new struc((char) 0x649, (char) 0xfef0, (char) 0xfeef,
                (char) 0xfef0, (char) 0xfeef),
        new struc((char) 0x631, (char) 0xfeae, (char) 0xfead,
                (char) 0xfeae, (char) 0xfead),
        new struc((char) 0x624, (char) 0xfe86, (char) 0xfe85,
                (char) 0xfe86, (char) 0xfe85),
        new struc((char) 0x621, (char) 0xfe80, (char) 0xfe80,
                (char) 0xfe80, (char) 0xfe80),
        new struc((char) 0x626, (char) 0xfe8a, (char) 0xfe8b,
                (char) 0xfe8c, (char) 0xfe89),
        new struc((char) 0x623, (char) 0xfe84, (char) 0xfe83,
                (char) 0xfe84, (char) 0xfe83),
        new struc((char) 0x622, (char) 0xfe82, (char) 0xfe81,
                (char) 0xfe82, (char) 0xfe81),
        new struc((char) 0x625, (char) 0xfe88, (char) 0xfe87,
                (char) 0xfe88, (char) 0xfe87),
        new struc((char) 0x67e, (char) 0xfb57, (char) 0xfb58,
                (char) 0xfb59, (char) 0xfb56), // peh
        new struc((char) 0x686, (char) 0xfb7b, (char) 0xfb7c,
                (char) 0xfb7d, (char) 0xfb7a), // cheh
        new struc((char) 0x698, (char) 0xfb8b, (char) 0xfb8a,
                (char) 0xfb8b, (char) 0xfb8a), // jeh
        new struc((char) 0x6a9, (char) 0xfb8f, (char) 0xfb90,
                (char) 0xfb91, (char) 0xfb8e), // keheh
        new struc((char) 0x6af, (char) 0xfb93, (char) 0xfb94,
                (char) 0xfb95, (char) 0xfb92), // gaf
        // new struc((char) 0x6cc, (char) 0xfbfd, (char) 0xfbfe,
        // (char) 0xfbff, (char) 0xfbfc), // Farsi yeh
        new struc((char) 0x6cc, (char) 0xfbfd, (char) 0xfef3,
                (char) 0xfef4, (char) 0xfbfc), // Arabic yeh
        new struc((char) 0x6c0, (char) 0xfba5, (char) 0xfba4,
                (char) 0xfba5, (char) 0xfba4) // heh with yeh
};

static struc[] arrStrucWoosim = {
        new struc((char) 0x630, (char) 0xb5, (char) 0x82, (char) 0xb5,
                (char) 0x82),
        new struc((char) 0x62f, (char) 0xb4, (char) 0x81, (char) 0xb4,
                (char) 0x81),
        new struc((char) 0x62c, (char) 0x9b, (char) 0xb1, (char) 0xf9,
                (char) 0xbf),
        new struc((char) 0x62d, (char) 0x9c, (char) 0xb2, (char) 0xfa,
                (char) 0xc0),
        new struc((char) 0x62e, (char) 0x9d, (char) 0xb3, (char) 0xfe,
                (char) 0xc1),
        new struc((char) 0x647, (char) 0xac, (char) 0xe4, (char) 0x93,
                (char) 0xd5),
        new struc((char) 0x639, (char) 0xc9, (char) 0xd3, (char) 0x8b,
                (char) 0xa4),
        new struc((char) 0x63a, (char) 0xca, (char) 0xdd, (char) 0x8c,
                (char) 0xa5),
        new struc((char) 0x641, (char) 0xa6, (char) 0xde, (char) 0x8d,
                (char) 0xcc),
        new struc((char) 0x642, (char) 0xa7, (char) 0xdf, (char) 0x8e,
                (char) 0xce),
        new struc((char) 0x62b, (char) 0xbd, (char) 0xaf, (char) 0xea,
                (char) 0x99),
        new struc((char) 0x635, (char) 0xc4, (char) 0xc8, (char) 0x87,
                (char) 0xa0),
        new struc((char) 0x636, (char) 0xc5, (char) 0xcb, (char) 0x88,
                (char) 0xa1),
        new struc((char) 0x637, (char) 0xc6, (char) 0xcd, (char) 0xcd,
                (char) 0xa2),
        new struc((char) 0x643, (char) 0xcf, (char) 0xe0, (char) 0x8f,
                (char) 0xa8),
        new struc((char) 0x645, (char) 0xd2, (char) 0xe2, (char) 0x91,
                (char) 0xaa),
        new struc((char) 0x646, (char) 0xd4, (char) 0xe3, (char) 0x92,
                (char) 0xab),
        new struc((char) 0x62a, (char) 0xbd, (char) 0xaf, (char) 0xea,
                (char) 0x99),
        new struc((char) 0x627, (char) 0xbb, (char) 0x80, (char) 0xbb,
                (char) 0x80),
        new struc((char) 0x644, (char) 0xd1, (char) 0xe1, (char) 0x90,
                (char) 0xa9),
        new struc((char) 0x628, (char) 0xbc, (char) 0xae, (char) 0xe9,
                (char) 0x98),
        new struc((char) 0x64a, (char) 0xdc, (char) 0xe6, (char) 0x95,
                (char) 0xdc),
        new struc((char) 0x633, (char) 0xc2, (char) 0xb8, (char) 0xb8,
                (char) 0x9e),
        new struc((char) 0x634, (char) 0xc3, (char) 0xb9, (char) 0xb9,
                (char) 0x9f),
        new struc((char) 0x638, (char) 0xc7, (char) 0xcd, (char) 0xcd,
                (char) 0xc7),
        new struc((char) 0x632, (char) 0xb7, (char) 0xb7, (char) 0xb7,
                (char) 0xb7),
        new struc((char) 0x648, (char) 0x94, (char) 0x94, (char) 0x94,
                (char) 0x94),
        new struc((char) 0x629, (char) 0xda, (char) 0xda, (char) 0xda,
                (char) 0xda),
        new struc((char) 0x649, (char) 0xdc, (char) 0xe6, (char) 0x95,
                (char) 0xdc),
        new struc((char) 0x631, (char) 0xb6, (char) 0xb6, (char) 0xb6,
                (char) 0xb6),
        new struc((char) 0x624, (char) 0xe7, (char) 0xe7, (char) 0xe7,
                (char) 0xe7),
        new struc((char) 0x621, (char) 0xba, (char) 0xba, (char) 0xba,
                (char) 0xba),
        new struc((char) 0x626, (char) 0xd7, (char) 0xe8, (char) 0x97,
                (char) 0xd7),
        new struc((char) 0x623, (char) 0x80, (char) 0x80, (char) 0x80,
                (char) 0x80),
        new struc((char) 0x622, (char) 0x80, (char) 0x80, (char) 0x80,
                (char) 0x80),
        new struc((char) 0x625, (char) 0x80, (char) 0x80, (char) 0x80,
                (char) 0x80),
        new struc((char) 0x67e, (char) 0xbc, (char) 0xae, (char) 0xe9,
                (char) 0x98), // peh
        new struc((char) 0x686, (char) 0x9b, (char) 0xb1, (char) 0xf9,
                (char) 0xbf), // cheh
        new struc((char) 0x698, (char) 0xb7, (char) 0xb7, (char) 0xb7,
                (char) 0xb7), // jeh
        new struc((char) 0x6a9, (char) 0xcf, (char) 0xe0, (char) 0x8f,
                (char) 0xa8), // keheh
        new struc((char) 0x6af, (char) 0xcf, (char) 0xe0, (char) 0x8f,
                (char) 0xa8), // gaf
        new struc((char) 0x6cc, (char) 0xdc, (char) 0xe6, (char) 0x95,
                (char) 0xdc), // yeh
        new struc((char) 0x6c0, (char) 0xac, (char) 0xe4, (char) 0x93,
                (char) 0xd5) // heh with yeh
};

private static final int N_DISTINCT_CHARACTERS = 43;

private static final String ArabicReverse(String s) {
    try {
        String Out = "", rev;
        s = MakeReverse(s);
        char[] chs = new char[s.length()];
        chs = s.toCharArray();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < s.length()) {
            if ((chs[i] >= '0' && chs[i] <= '9')) // isDigit(s[i]) ?
            {
                rev = "";
                while (i < s.length()
                        && ((chs[i] >= '0' && chs[i] <= '9') || chs[i] == '/')) // isDigit(s[i])
                                                                                // ?
                {
                    rev = rev + chs[i];
                    ++i;
                }
                rev = MakeReverse(rev);
                Out = Out + rev;
            } else {
                Out = Out + chs[i];
                ++i;
            }
        }
        s = Out;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // throw new Exception(
        // "An exception has occurred in ArabicReverse function.\\n"
        // + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return s;
}

private static final boolean isFromTheSet1(/* WCHAR */char ch) {
    char[] theSet1 = new char[] { (char) 0x62c, (char) 0x62d, (char) 0x62e,
            (char) 0x647, (char) 0x639, (char) 0x63a, (char) 0x641,
            (char) 0x642, (char) 0x62b, (char) 0x635, (char) 0x636,
            (char) 0x637, (char) 0x643, (char) 0x645, (char) 0x646,
            (char) 0x62a, (char) 0x644, (char) 0x628, (char) 0x64a,
            (char) 0x633, (char) 0x634, (char) 0x638, (char) 0x67e,
            (char) 0x686, (char) 0x6a9, (char) 0x6af, (char) 0x6cc,
            (char) 0x626 };
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 28) {
        if (ch == theSet1[i])
            return true;
        ++i;
    }
    return false;
}

private static final boolean isFromTheSet2(/* WCHAR */char ch) {
    char[] theSet2 = new char[] { (char) 0x627, (char) 0x623, (char) 0x625,
            (char) 0x622, (char) 0x62f, (char) 0x630, (char) 0x631,
            (char) 0x632, (char) 0x648, (char) 0x624, (char) 0x629,
            (char) 0x649, (char) 0x698, (char) 0x6c0 };
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 14) {
        if (ch == theSet2[i])
            return true;
        ++i;
    }
    return false;
}

private static final String MakeReverse(String text) {
    String Result = "";
    char[] Ctext = new char[text.length()];
    Ctext = text.toCharArray();
    for (int i = (text.length()) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        Result += Ctext[i];
    }
    return Result;
}

public static final String ConvertBackToRealFarsi(String In) {

    if (!isFarsiConversionNeeded) {
        return In;
    }

    String strOut = "";
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder("");
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    char[] chIn = new char[In.length()];
    chIn = In.toCharArray();

    for (i = 0; i < In.length(); i++) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (j = 0; j < arrStruc.length; j++) {
            if (chIn[i] == arrStruc[j].midGlyph ||
                    chIn[i] == arrStruc[j].iniGlyph ||
                    chIn[i] == arrStruc[j].endGlyph ||
                    chIn[i] == arrStruc[j].isoGlyph) {
                strBuilder.append(arrStruc[j].character);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found)
            strBuilder.append(chIn[i]);
    }

    strOut = strBuilder.toString();
strOut = strOut.replace(szLa, "لا");
strOut = strOut.replace(szLaStick, "لا");

    return strOut;
}

public static final String Convert(String In) {

    if (!isFarsiConversionNeeded) {
        return In;
    }

    if (In == null) {
        return "";
    }

    boolean linkBefore, linkAfter;
    String Out = In;
    char[] chOut = new char[Out.length()];
    chOut = Out.toCharArray();
    char[] chIn = new char[In.length()];
    chIn = In.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < In.length(); i++) {
        /* WCHAR */
        char ch = chIn[i];
        if ((ch >= (char) 0x0621 && ch <= (char) 0x064a)
                || (ch == (char) 0x067e) || (ch == (char) 0x0686)
                || (ch == (char) 0x0698) || (ch == (char) 0x06a9)
                || (ch == (char) 0x06af) || (ch == (char) 0x06cc)
                || (ch == (char) 0x06c0)) // is a Farsi character?
        {
            int idx = 0;
            while (idx < N_DISTINCT_CHARACTERS) {
                if (arrStruc[idx].character == chIn[i])
                    break;
                ++idx;
            }

            if (i == In.length() - 1)
                linkAfter = false;
            else
                linkAfter = (isFromTheSet1(chIn[i + 1]) || isFromTheSet2(chIn[i + 1]));
            if (i == 0)
                linkBefore = false;
            else
                linkBefore = isFromTheSet1(chIn[i - 1]);
            if (idx < N_DISTINCT_CHARACTERS) {
                if (linkBefore && linkAfter)
                    chOut[i] = arrStruc[idx].midGlyph;
                if (linkBefore && !linkAfter)
                    chOut[i] = arrStruc[idx].endGlyph;
                if (!linkBefore && linkAfter)
                    chOut[i] = arrStruc[idx].iniGlyph;
                if (!linkBefore && !linkAfter)
                    chOut[i] = arrStruc[idx].isoGlyph;
            } else {
                chOut[i] = chIn[i];
            }
        } else {
            chOut[i] = chIn[i];
        }
    }
    Out = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < chOut.length; j++)
        Out += chOut[j];
    // Out = ArabicReverse(Out);

    Out = Out.replace((char) 0x200c, ' '); // Change NO SPACE to SPACE

    Out = Out.replace(szLamAndAlef, szLa); // Join 'Lam' and 'Alef' and
                                            // make 'La'
    Out = Out.replace(szLamStickAndAlef, szLaStick); // Join 'Lam Stick'
                                                        // and 'Alef'
                                                        // and make 'La
                                                        // Stick'

    return reorderWords(Out);

}

private final static String reorderWords(String strIn)
{

    final int ST_RTL = 0;
    final int ST_LTR = 1;

    String strOut = "";
    String prevWord = "";
    int state = ST_RTL;
    char[] arr = strIn.toCharArray();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < arr.length) {
        if (charIsLTR(arr[i]) && state != ST_LTR)
        {
            // state changed to LTR
            state = ST_LTR;
            strOut = prevWord + strOut;
            prevWord = "";
            prevWord += arr[i];
        }
        else if (charIsRTL(arr[i]) && state != ST_RTL)
        {
            // state changed to RTL
            state = ST_RTL;
            strOut = prevWord + strOut;
            prevWord = "";
            prevWord += arr[i];
        }
        else
        {
            // state is not changed
            prevWord += arr[i];
        }
        i++;
    }

    strOut = prevWord + strOut;

    return strOut;

}

private final static boolean charIsLTR(char ch)
{
    return (ch >= (char) 65 & ch <= (char) 122)
            |
            Character.isDigit(ch);
}

private final static boolean charIsRTL(char ch)
{
    return ch >= (char) 0x0621;
}   

private static Typeface typeface;

public static final Typeface GetFarsiFont(Context context) {
    if (typeface == null) {
        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                // "DroidSansFallback.ttf");
                "TAHOMA.TTF");
    }
    return typeface;
}
```

}

Comment: DynamicPDF is a library that needs to be purchased if not making a "proof of concept" or internal application.

Comment: It's free to download, but you need to read the license if you plan to publish your code on the Google Play store. It is not under an open license - so if you want to distribute it in an app, you need to purchase a professional edition library.